# How can I determine in the resource server which grant type was used by the client?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I have my Web API configured to use Identity Server 4 in a way that it uses the client claims and the user claims to implement authorization on endpoints.

The problem here is that I need to know which grant type was used by the client app to customize that authorization mechanism. For example, if the client used client credentials, then the user claims will not be available.

Is there any way to determine the grant type used by the client app, programmatically when the request hits the Web API endpoint?

The Web API setups Identity Server as follows:

```
services
.AddAuthorization(
    (options) =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            Policies.Monitoring, 
            (policy) =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", Policies.Scopes.Monitoring);
            });

        options.AddPolicy(
            Policies.VatNumber,
            (policy) =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", Policies.Scopes.VatNumber);
                policy.Requirements.Add(new ClientSubscriptionRequirement());
            });
    });

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ClientSubscriptionAuthorizationHandler>();

services
.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
    (options) =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "datalookup";
    });
```

I need to know the client app grant type in the `ClientSubscriptionAuthorizationHandler`.

Comment: You could a claim to the token to denote that. Worth checking to see if there’s a relevant convention out there already.

Comment: Please share your code related to your setup.

Comment: I've updated the question with the setup code.